# Why does JAVAFX with NetBeans output low quality error messages

Tags: javafx

Why does JAVAFX with Netbeans bring such low detailed error messages that are the same for every error you get?

No matter what error I get I still get no hint about where the code stops.

This is the "greek" error message I get...

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1768)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)  at
>   javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)    at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)    at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1763)     ...
>   47 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javafx.scene.chart.PieChart$Data cannot be cast to
>   javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series     at
>   javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$2.onChanged(XYChart.java:121)  at
>   javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$3.invalidated(XYChart.java:210)    at
>   javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
>     at
>   javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
>     at
>   javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty.setValue(ObjectProperty.java:69)
>     at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.setData(XYChart.java:242)     at
>   tabletopiechart.FXMLDocumentController.handleButtonAction3(FXMLDocumentController.java:65)
>     ... 57 more

Comment: The error is specified here `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.chart.PieChart$Data cannot be cast to javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$2.onChanged(XYChart.java:121)`. **Please check line no 65 of `FXMLDocumentController`**

Comment: is it always the last line that provides the correct error message?

Comment: No, it depends ! You need to check the stackTrace and find the culprit !